# Lambda Function as a Zip with Layer as a Docker Image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

My entire lambda functions architecture is built around the .zip package type. I create a separate layer.zip for dependencies that are shared across but it recently crossed the 250 MB limit.

**I'm not keen on moving my lambda functions to docker container images.**

But I can happily docker containerize my layers.

Is there any way to use create/use a docker container image as a layer and attach it to a .zip lambda function?

Does this serve as a solution to get past the 250 MB layer limit?

Look forward to any feedback and resources! :)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: they're two different ways of implementing your Lambda. In the "traditional" style, your code is deployed into an AWS-managed runtime that invokes your functions. In the "container" style, your container must implement that runtime.

While I think that 250 MB is an indication that Lambda is the wrong technology choice, you *can* work-around it by downloading additional content into `/tmp` when your Lambda first starts.

This is easier for languages such as Python, where you can update `sys.path` on the fly. It's much less easy (but still doable) for languages like Java, where you'd need a "wrapper" function that then creates a classpath for the downloaded JARs.

It's also easier if the bulk of your Lambda is a static resource, like an ML model, rather than code.

Comment: Hey @Parsifal, thanks for the response. The large size is due my node_modules layer. And it's before of just one mondule that is bloating my entire layer. Not much of a choice tehere.

But it seems docker image is the best way to go about in future.